Missing order of execution on class
Multiple times, I find myself in the same situation.
My types are not correct and I need to do extra verification somewhere.
I have created a very simple example, we have a Car class, inside we can retrieve a model name. When we initialised this class, the model is null.
We have one function to set and one to get the model:
class Car {
    private model: string | null

    setModel() {
        this.model = 'a3'
    }
  
    getModel() {
        return this.model
    }
}

When we use this class, everything works like expected, and, in order of execution, we can see that model can only be defined.
But, TypeScript will only take the original type and only know that it is a string or null.
function searchForBrand(model: string) {
    if (model === 'a3') return 'audi'

    return ''
}


const car = new Car()
car.setModel()

console.log(car) // { model: 'a3' }

const currentModel = car.getModel()
console.log(currentModel) // a3

searchForBrand(currentModel) // Error: Argument of type 'string | null'

I need to use ! (but it is pretty bad to use it, no?), or handle this possibility in my function or before.
This seems extra works, and not the right solution. Does it?
Playground
The real example where i have a similar problem:
class Stream {
  idealConstraint = {
    width: { ideal: 1920 },
    height: { ideal: 1080 },
    frameRate: { ideal: 60 },
    advanced: [ { zoom: 2 } ]
  }
  flux: MediaStream | null = null

  async useStreamWithConstraints() {
    const constraints = {
      video: {
        facingMode: FACING_MODE.ENVIRONMENT,
        noiseSuppression: true,
      },
      audio: false
    }
  
    await this.useUserStream(constraints)
    if (APP_MODE === 'development') await this.useDevelopmentStream() 

    await this.applyVideoConstraints(this.idealConstraint)
    
    return this.flux
  }

  async useUserStream(constraints: MediaStreamConstraints) {
    this.flux = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  }

  async useDevelopmentStream() {
    const developmentDeviceId = (await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()).filter(device => device.label === 'OBS Virtual Camera')[0]?.deviceId
    const developmentStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { deviceId: developmentDeviceId } })
    const developmentStreamDeviceId = developmentStream.getVideoTracks()[0]?.getCapabilities()?.deviceId

    if (developmentStreamDeviceId === developmentDeviceId) this.flux = developmentStream
  }

  async applyVideoConstraints(constraints: MediaTrackConstraints) {
    try {
      const videoTrack = this.flux?.getVideoTracks()[0]
      await videoTrack?.applyConstraints(constraints)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Could not apply constraints')
    }
  }

  getFluxSettings() {
    return this.flux?.getVideoTracks()[0]?.getSettings()
  }

  getFluxCapabilities() {
    return this.flux?.getVideoTracks()[0]?.getCapabilities()
  }

  setZoom(zoomValue: number) {
    return this.applyVideoConstraints({
      advanced: [{ zoom: zoomValue }]
    })
  }
}


It's doing exactly what it's supposed to. If that value could be null, as your types say, that needs to be handled. Much better would be to not allow an invalid Car to be created to start with, so it can just be typed as model: string.

I understand. But in that case, it's mandatory to use the constructor?
Or there is other way?
Because, in case of complex class, i will have to pass in parameter the property, and at the end return it inside the constructor to assign it.
If i assign it in the function directly this will not works too.
https://shorturl.at/mS0rH

That's way the builder design pattern is used for complex classes. You can create a CarBuilder that allows invalid values. The build method validates the properties and creates the car. The example is pretty similar to your code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

"The real example where i have a similar problem:" What's the difference between your first example and the real example? It looks similar. You should always ask yourself: does flux: MediaStream | null = null make sense? Is flux = null a valid case? If yes, you have to handle null. If not, initialize the property in the constructor and use flux: MediaStream

@jabaa Yes, I agree. It's just that it seems not clean to call inside the constructor the function and each have to pass the flux and return it inside the constructor to assign it.
But, like you say, maybe that's the best solution to this, because the flux not make sens to null indeed. I have only done that to have a proper structure.

It seems like "clean" and "proper structure" is opinion-based and we have two different opinions.

It's not clear what you mean by "call inside the constructor the function and each have to pass the flux and return it inside the constructor to assign it" - can you elaborate?

It appears that your real problem here is the asynchronous initialisation of this.flux = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints). Your class instance is not really usable until you have called (and awaited) useUserStream(), which is a bad practice. Solve this kind of problem by having a static method to construct an instance with a flux - then you can use the appropriate types without any null values and write code without optional chaining.

I mean I have to call inside the constructor useStreamWithConstraints, and inside it called useUserStream that return a stream, and called useDevelopmentStream that return a stream, and return the stream in useStreamWithConstraints and assign it inside the constructor.
Whereas with direct attachment (this) I don't need to do this, but we can't initialise the property outside of the constructor, even if it's in the function called by the constructor.
Thanks for the comment and issue, I will try, I think this help me to understand what I want.

"I mean I have to..." No, you don't have to and you're right. That's not clean. You got two options. Use a builder class/function or use a static method that creates an instance.

Yes, thanks a lot for the details, the two-way are the good one.

Please don't add answers to your question. You can post an actual answer.

As @jonrsharpe has already explained in his comment, it might be a better idea to not let any invalid Car instances be created and instead pass the model inside a constructor so it can be set upon creating the Car instance.
class Car {
    constructor(private model: string){}
  
    getModel(): string {
        return this.model
    }
}

function searchForBrand(model: string) {
    if (model === 'a3') return 'audi'

    return ''
}


const car = new Car('a3')

const currentModel = car.getModel()
searchForBrand(currentModel)

Playground

If it can help someone, this is the updated code.
If I miss something, you can comment it.
Thanks for the explanation all.
class Stream {
  static idealConstraint = {
    width: { ideal: 1920 },
    height: { ideal: 1080 },
    frameRate: { ideal: 60 },
    advanced: [ { zoom: 2 } ]
  }
  flux: MediaStream

  constructor(flux: MediaStream) {
    this.flux = flux
  }

  static async create() {
    const flux = await this.#getUserFlux()
    const developmentFlux = await this.#getDevelopmentFlux()
    const usedFlux = developmentFlux ?? flux

    await this.#applyFluxConstraints(usedFlux, this.idealConstraint)

    return new this(usedFlux)
  }

  static #getUserFlux() {
    const constraints = {
      video: {
        facingMode: FACING_MODE.ENVIRONMENT,
        noiseSuppression: true,
      },
      audio: false
    }

    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  }

  static async #getDevelopmentFlux() {
    if (APP_MODE !== 'development') return

    const developmentDeviceId = (await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()).filter(device => device.label === 'OBS Virtual Camera')[0]?.deviceId
    if (!developmentDeviceId) return

    const developmentStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { deviceId: { exact: developmentDeviceId } } })

    return developmentStream
  }

  static async #applyFluxConstraints(flux: MediaStream, constraint: MediaTrackConstraints) {
    try {
      const videoTrack = flux.getVideoTracks()[0]
      await videoTrack.applyConstraints(constraint)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Could not apply constraints')
    }
  }

  get currentZoom() {
    return this.flux.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().zoom
  }

  getFluxCapabilities() {
    return this.flux.getVideoTracks()[0].getCapabilities()
  }

  setZoom(zoomValue: number) {
    const zoomConstraint = {
      advanced: [{ zoom: zoomValue }]
    }

    return Stream.#applyFluxConstraints(this.flux, zoomConstraint)
  }
}

